# AWS GraphQL: Sort List by specific sort key

Tags: reactjs, react-native, graphql, aws-appsync, dynamodb-queries

Considering the given schema declaration:

```
type Subject @model @key(fields: ["num", "type", "desc", "parent"])
{
    id:     ID!
    num :   String!
    ...
}
```

How would I call `API.graphql` method in order to sort it by its 3rd key, for instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

GraphQL doesn't inherently support sorting. To add sorting you need to modify your queries to accept one or more sort parameters and then do the sorting in your code. This article gives examples of [Filtering, Pagination & Sorting](https://www.howtographql.com/graphql-js/8-filtering-pagination-and-sorting/).